# How can we push data from Azure Service Bus to Sales Force

Tags: salesforce, azure-servicebus-queues

How can we push data from Azure Service Bus to Sales Force. I need to send data to sales force when new message received on azure topic.

Answer (score 1):

If Azure Logic App is possible, I recommand that you could use Azure Logic to do that.

You could follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-servicebus#trigger-workflow-when-your-service-bus-gets-new-messages) to set up service bus trigger in the logic App, after that you could use Sales Force connetor to do what you want.

For Sales Force connetor, please refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-salesforce#connect-to-salesforce-connector). For more information about logic App please reference to this [document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/logic-apps/).

[image]